# GIT - Multiple repos - List all touched/dirty files (example Android build system)

Tags: git, android-build, repo, forall

In a typical multiple repo scenario like Android build system (where kernel is a git repo, framework/base is a different git repo, bootable/bootlaoder/lk  etc..) it becomes difficult to track all the changed files in all the repos.

A practical issue is say if most of your changes are spread across  1 or 2 major components (like kernel and framwork/base) you might miss to commit a minor change in a different repo.

**Question is:** Is there a single command that I can fire from the root folder that does the job
Pls note if possible I would try to avoid installing new software/packages - any working solution with `repo` /`git` would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution using `repo forall` :-

```
zhossain@zhossain-linux:/local/mnt/workspace/LE.UM.0.0_2_13$ repo forall -pc "git diff --name-only"

project bootable/bootloader/lk/
target/msm8909/init.c

project frameworks/
av/media/mtp/MtpMain.cpp

project kernel/msm-3.18/
arch/arm/boot/dts/qcom/apq8017-no-pmi-wcd-rome-cdp.dts
arch/arm/boot/dts/qcom/msm8917-pinctrl.dtsi
arch/arm64/configs/msm8937_defconfig
zhossain@zhossain-linux:/local/mnt/workspace/LE.UM.0.0_2_13$
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, but you need to make sure your it doesn't conflict with "repo"

you can create a git project to track submodules, that is the parent of the android build dir.

gitkraken has a nice guide on it.

https://support.gitkraken.com/repositories/submodules

I used gitkraken to learn, because I'm a visual learner

once you get comfortable, you can leave that parent git, and use repo branches, to track your projects,

repo branch, repo branches
repo info, repo status, repo show

Comment: Thanks for the pointers - but am looking not to use any additional utility software